# How to configure kmail2 to use client certificates for POP3 and IMAP access

Tags: email, certificates, kmail

I would like to run a POP3 server with TLS transport security such that a client must authenticate with a client certificate. (This shields the server from brute force password guessing attacks.)

How can I configure kmail2 (KDE 4.12.5) accordingly?  There is no obvious (to me) configuration setting for client certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request I do not think this capability is currently supported by kmail2. At least that's the look of things according to these 2 tickets in the project's issue tracker.

- [Bug 305396 - Add client certificate authentication to KMail2](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=305396)
- [Bug 131083 - Add client certificate authentication to KMail](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=131083)

It does support the following things:

- Supports the standard mail protocols IMAP, POP3 and SMTP
- Supports plain text and secure logins, using SSL and TLS
- Native support for inline OpenPGP, PGP/MIME, and S/MIME

These bullets are right from the main website:

- https://userbase.kde.org/KMail

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. KDE 4 as a whole fails to deal with client certificates. Too bad...